# Why Navigation properties are missing?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I worked on a project before. The database was Access. I converted it to SQL Server (with data) and used Entity Framework 4.4 (database first), everything worked fine. Recently, we need to add some more tables, add some columns to existing tables, and add some foreign key to these tables. Now, I delete the .edmx and .tt files, dd a new .edmx which uses the new database, for some reasons, several foreign keys are not shown as navigation properties in the tables.

Now, if I convert the Access to SQL again without data, make the same database schema change, delete the .edmx and .tt in the old project, then add new .edmx file, oddly, more navigation properties show up, but still not all of them.

I also upgrade to Entity 5 and 6.0.1, same results.

Anyone had the same issue before? Any clue of what may cause this? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It is because the Access has some indexes on some columns. One index is like the ID of the table. After convert to SQL, the index still exists on ID column, and I create a PK on that column in the conversion, then FK on other tables to pointing to this PK. So, now, the column has 2 index, one is unique non-clustered, and one is clustered. Maybe Entity framework does not like this?

After I remove the Unique non-clustered index, it works fine now.

Maybe someone knows more about why it matters.

Thanks